# C: scanf() hanging, getchar() not working to clear input

Tags: c, input, scanf, getchar

The function is supposed to prompt a user for input, and then return a value, however it keeps hanging.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int foo(void) {
    printf("return something ");
    char input;
    scanf("%d", &input);
    while (getchar() != '\n') {}
    printf("input: %d\n", input);
    return input;
}

int main()
{
    int t = foo();
    printf("foo() returned: %d\n", t);
    return 0;
}
```

OUTPUT

```
return something 4                                                                                                     
input: 4                                                                                                               
foo() returned: 4                                                                                                      
Segmentation fault                                                                                                     
                                                                                                                       
                                                                                                                       
...Program finished with exit code 139                                                                                 
Press ENTER to exit console.
```

I've tried scanf(" %d", &choice) as well, but to no avail. If its relevant, this code is part of  something that is eventually compiled into a .o file and then linked to main(), where it's called.

Comment: [Can't reproduce](https://ideone.com/pZFsQI). Please provide a [complete minimal verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)  and show your exact run log.

Comment: @kaylum#include <stdio.h>

`int foo(void) {
    printf("return something ");
    char input;
    scanf("%d", &input);
    while (getchar() != '\n') {}
    printf("input: %d\n", input);
    return input;
}

int main()
{
    int t = foo();
    printf("foo() returned: %d\n", t);
    return 0;
}`

Comment: Don't put the code in a comment, update your question

Comment: @lxop just did, my bad

Comment: The log you have shown is not a "hang" as you described in the question. It's already gotten way past the `getchar` and has even printed the result in `main`. Please describe the situation more clearly.

Comment: Surely your compiler gives a warning similar to: `warning: format specifies type 'int *' but the argument has type 'char *' [-Wformat]
    scanf("%d", &input);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are reading the input with code `%d` but you are asking to put it into a variable of type `char` - that variable is too small. If you change `char input` to `int input` it works: https://ideone.com/KpLH25